# 404 returned when I use %2F in request url path on Google App Engine/Python Production

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I get 404 not found response when I use a parameter which include '%2f' in url path on Google App Engine/Python (only on production server, not on my mac development server).

I use Kay-framework(http://kay-docs.shehas.net/index.html) as my GAE/Python framework.

I set url routing like below.

```
Rule('/rest/article/<string:article_id>', endpoint='article',view='myapp.views.article'),
```

and request to this url works fine in my Mac development server. Server returns 200 OK.

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/article/foobar%2Bfoobar%2Ffoobar => 200
```

But, when I send request to this url on GAE production server, GAE server returns 404.

```
http://foo-bar-app.appspot.com/rest/article/foobar%2Bfoobar%2Ffoobar => 404
```

I have to use parameters which include "/" (url encoded to "%2f").

Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I have just run into this problem myself. As I have control over the URL, I can escape the '%' itself, which is then recognised by GAE correctly. ie:

```
linkUrl = string.replace(linkUrl, '%2F', '%252F') # Workaround to avoid %2F issue on GAE servers
```

Ugly, but works in my case.

Comment: thanks for this solution.that must be the advancement from which the people always talk... apache gets more and more uninteresting